# Kafka Connect with MongoDB Connector

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have tried to use Apache Kafka Connect with MongoDB sink connector ([connector](https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-mongodb/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect))

When I used Avro format it worked except of one issue, I had to create the topic with one partition because the connector uses record.kafkaOffset() for the _id of the new Mongo record (so with multi partitions I get the same id for different records).

How can I fix it?

I would like to test it with Json so I created a new topic for that. And changed the converter configurations to JsonConverter. When I run it I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongodbSinkTask.put(MongodbSinkTask.java:106)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:280)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:176)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTaskThread.iteration(WorkerSinkTaskThread.java:90)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTaskThread.execute(WorkerSinkTaskThread.java:58)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:82)

Does this connector work with Json?

Comment: We've also experienced the issues you described when using this connector, thus we wrote our own MongoDB sink connector. You can try it: https://github.com/startappdev/kafka-connect-mongodb